# Conditional pmf involving the game Napoleon's War

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> In the board game *Napoleon’s War* the following can possibly occur:
>
> • The French player moves two of his cannons within range of two
>   British cannons.
>
> • The two British cannons “fire” at the two French cannons. This is
>   done by rolling one 6-sided die for each British cannon. For each die
>   that results in one or two spots on it’s upwards face, a French cannon
>   is eliminated.
>
> • Then each French cannon which has not been eliminated can “fire” at
>   the British cannons. This is done by rolling one 6-sided die for each
>   French cannon which wasn’t eliminated by the British. For each die that
>   results in one or two spots on it’s upwards face, a British cannon is
>   eliminated.
>
> Let $X$ be the number of French cannons eliminated in the scenerio
>   described above, and let $Y$ be the number of British cannons
>   eliminated in the scenerio described above. Give the conditional pmf
>   of $Y$ given that $X= 0$.

$$P(X=0 \cap Y=0)= {\frac{4}{6}}^4 = \frac{16}{81}$$

$$P(X=0 \cap Y=1)= {\frac{4}{6}}^2 \cdot {2\choose{1}} \cdot \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{16}{81}$$

$$P(X=0 \cap Y=2)= {\frac{4}{6}}^2 \cdot \frac{2}{6}^2 = \frac{4}{81}$$

Thus, I have the following table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline X & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline Y & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline p & \frac{16}{81} & \frac{16}{81} &  \frac{4}{81}\\\hline\end{array}$$

The sum of these values is $\frac{36}{81}$ so dividing each of these probabilities by that I get

$$ P_{Y}(y | X=0)=  
\begin{cases} 
\frac{4}{9} & y=0 \\
\frac{4}{9} & y=1 \\
\frac{1}{9} & y=2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Is this a valid solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution appears correct, but the approach overly cumbersome, with questionable intermediate terms.

Easier to consider that with $X=0$, Y describes the number of successes for N=2 tries with success probability p=1/3. That is the binomial distribution.